# Add/Change text inside pager area of Telerik's Grid in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, telerik, telerik-grid

I would like to be able to add some custom text within the built in pager area of Telerik's Grid component for Blazor. It would also be nice to be able to change the predefined text, but the image below shows what I would like to accomplish.

[image: Telerik Grid Pager]

I have found several resources showing how to do this using other Telerik products, but I haven't been able to find anything for Blazor. Here is an example I found for Kendo UI for Angular [Changing the text of the paging area in the grid](https://www.telerik.com/forums/changing-the-text-of-the-paging-area-in-the-grid-f1d12803c2d6) and another one I found but for ASP.NET AJAX [Change label text of pager item](https://www.telerik.com/forums/change-label-text-of-pager-item). However, these did not help me much.

Does anyone know of a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want custom markup within the Pager, they have a logged item for that - https://feedback.telerik.com/blazor/1557339-pager-template
If you just want to update the label/s, you should be able to do this through the localization strings - https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/globalization/localization